# Accepting / returning XML/JSON request and response - Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I need to write a rest service which accepts XML/JSON as a input (POST method) and XML/JSON as a output (based on the input format). I have tried a below approach to achieve this but doesn't helped out.Endpoint method accepts both XML/JSON but while responding it always gives either JSON or XML based on the order specified in @RequestMapping -produces.Any help will be really appreciated.

My endpoint method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getxmljson", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces={"application/json","application/xml"},
        consumes={"application/json", "application/xml"})
public @ResponseBody Student processXMLJsonRequest(@RequestBody Student student)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("*************Inside Controller");
    return student;
}
```

POJO Class: Student.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@XmlRootElement(name = "student")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"id", "name", "graduationTime", "courses"})
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "name", "graduationTime", "courses"})
public class Student implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String graduationTime;
    private ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();

    @XmlElement
    public int getId() { return id; }
    @XmlElement
    public String getName() { return name; }
    @XmlElement
    public String getGraduationTime() { return graduationTime; }
    @XmlElement
    public ArrayList<Course> getCourses() { return courses; }

    public void setId(int value) { this.id = value; }
    public void setName(String value) { this.name = value; }
    public void setGraduationTime(String value) { this.graduationTime = value; }
    public void setCourses(ArrayList<Course> value) { this.courses = value; }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + " - "
                + graduationTime == null? "Unknown" : graduationTime.toString();
    }

    public Student() {}
    public Student(int id, String name, String graduationTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.graduationTime = graduationTime;
    }
}
```

POJO Class: Course.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@XmlRootElement(name = "course")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"courseName", "score"})
@JsonPropertyOrder({"courseName", "score"})
public class Course implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String courseName;
    private Integer score;

    public @XmlElement String getCourseName() { return courseName; }
    public @XmlElement Integer getScore() { return score; }

    public void setCourseName(String value) { courseName = value; }
    public void setScore(Integer value) { score = value; }

    public Course() {}
    public Course(String courseName, Integer score) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
                <beans:ref bean="xmlMessageConverter" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="xmlMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">

    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="objectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />

</beans:beans>
```

Json Input:

```
{
"id":2014,
"name":"test",
"graduationtime":"09/05/2014",
"courses":[
{
"courseName":"Math",
"score":150
},
{
"courseName":"Che",
"score":150
}
]
}
```

XML Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<student>
<id>2014</id>
<name>test</name>
<graduationTime>09/05/2014</graduationTime>
<courses>
    <courseName>Math</courseName>
    <score>150</score>
</courses>
<courses>
    <courseName>Che</courseName>
    <score>150</score>
</courses>
</student>
```

Comment: Look this sample.  http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-restful/spring-rest-hello-world-xml-example/

Answer (score 35):

The best practice for handling different data formats with the same controller is to let the framework do all the work of figuring out the marshalling and unmarshalling mechanisms.

> **Step 1**: Use minimal controller configuration

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getxmljson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Student processXMLJsonRequest(@RequestBody Student student) {
  return student;
}
```

There is no need to specify `consumes` and `produces` here.  As an example, consider that you may want this same method to handle other formats in the future such as Google Protocol Buffers, EDI, etc.  Keeping the controllers free of `consumes` and `produces` will let you add data formats through global configuration instead of having to modify the controller code.

> **Step 2**: Use `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` instead of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="defaultViews">
      <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView"/>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Let the view resolver decide how to read incoming data and how to write it back.

> **Step 3**: Use `Accepts` and `Content-Type` HTTP headers

Hitting your controller with the correct HTTP header values will force `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` to marshal and unmarshal data automatically using the appropriate data representations.

If you want to exchange data in JSON format, set both headers to `application/json`.  If you want XML instead, set both to `application/xml`.

If you do not want to use HTTP headers (which ideally you should), you can simply add `.json` or `.xml` to the URL and `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` will do the rest.

---

You can check out [my sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/35270660) that I created using your code snippets that works fine for JSON and XML.

Comment: Would need additionally org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MappingJackson2XmlView to handle XML.

Answer (score 15):

Adding to Manish's answer above, if you don't wanna use xml based configuration use this java based configuration instead-

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver() {
    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver =
            new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();

    List<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
    views.add(new MappingJackson2XmlView());
    views.add(new MappingJackson2JsonView());

    resolver.setDefaultViews(views);
    return resolver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Register a filter that intercepts each request, warp the `HttpServletRequest` into an implementation of `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and returns the `Content-Type` value for `Accept` header. For example, you can register a filter named `SameInSameOutFilter` like following:

```
@Component
public class SameInSameOutFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        SameInSameOutRequest wrappedRequest = new SameInSameOutRequest((HttpServletRequest) request);
        chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, response);
    }
}
```

It wraps current request in a `SameInSameOutRequest`:

```
public class SameInSameOutRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    public SameInSameOutRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("accept")) {
            return getContentType();
        }

        return super.getHeader(name);
    }
}
```

This wrapper tells spring mvc to select a `HttpMessageConverter` based on request's `Content-Type` value. If request body's `Content-Type` is `application/xml`, then the response would be an `XML`. Otherwise, the response would be `JSON`.

The other solution is to manually set the `Accept` header along with `Content-Type` in each request and avoid all these hacks.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem like yours. Below is my solution and sample.

Below is maven dependency that you need to include:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven
        content-negotiation-manager="contentManager" />

<bean id="contentManager"
        class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="false" />
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
        <property name="useJaf" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

and my @RequestMapping ( you can use your own request mapping )

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testXMLJSON",
            method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    @ResponseBody
    public ArtworkContentMessageType testXMLJSON()
    {
        //this is GS1 xml standard mapping.
        ArtworkContentMessageType resp = new ArtworkContentMessageType();
        StandardBusinessDocumentHeader standarBusinessDocumentHeader = new StandardBusinessDocumentHeader();
        resp.setStandardBusinessDocumentHeader(standarBusinessDocumentHeader );
        ArtworkContentType artWorkContent = new ArtworkContentType();
        resp.getArtworkContent().add(artWorkContent);

        return resp ;
    }
```

If `application/xml` is required then, below headers must be present

```
Content-Type:application/xml
Accept:application/xml
```

Answer (score 0):

If the resource define as below

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Student getStudent(@PathParam("id") String  id) {
 return student(); // logic to retunrs student object
}
```

Then the request should contains 'accept' header ('application/json' or application/xml'),
then it returns response in json or xml format.

Sample request :

```
curl -k -X GET -H "accept: application/json" "https://172.17.0.5:8243/service/1.0/222"
```

Sample Student class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name = "student")
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String collegeName;
    private int age;
    @XmlAttribute
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getCollegeName() {
        return collegeName;
    }

    public void setCollegeName(String collegeName) {
        this.collegeName = collegeName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```