# How to set the response content type dynamically in Spring Rest Controller?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have implemented an API which will return both JSON and XML as per the client's request (i.e., Accept header in the request). Its working as expected.

The problem here is: even though user sends Accept header, on some special cases (i.e., business logic) we need to send the response content type dynamically.
I have tried to implement it using HttpHeaders but its not working.

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Response> getQueries(){
...............

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    //headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");  
    return new ResponseEntity<Response>(response, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I am geeting HTTP status as 200 but response as error i.e.,

```
Unexpected '<'
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270660/accepting-returning-xml-json-request-and-response-spring-mvc) can be very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is about Content-negotiation wich is a capability that allows consumer (your user agent) and provider (your controller) to agree from the get go on the response's mediatype

First of all, it is up to the APi consumer to indicate what mediatype(s) it will accept for the response. This is done by setting the Accept header to the required type(s). So in the case where the consumer expects a response type as JSON an Accept header should be configured with "application/json" or "application/xml" for XML (or any specific variation of each such as "application/xhtml+xml" and alike).

On the controller side, you need to specify the supported response mediatypes using the "produces" annotation property. There is also the sibling "consumes" property that specifies the supported request mediatype(s). Sooo... our mapping should look like:

```
@GetMapping(value="someEndpoint",
        produces={"application/json","application/xml"})
public ResponseEntity<Page<Person>> getPersons(
        @RequestParam(value = "page", required = true) Integer pPage,
        @RequestParam(value = "size", required = true) Integer pSize) 
{
    Page<Person>  result;
    result = personService.getPersons(new PageRequest(pPage, pSize));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Now the interesting part is that you don't have to bother with the response formatting since Spring will be able to detect the consumer required response mediatype based on the value of the http request Accept header.

Better yet, with the correct configuration, you can set the default response mediaType if there are no Accept header in the request. So, by setting the default response content type to "application/json", any request with no Accept header will be serviced in JSON while the consumer will have to add an Accept: "application/xml" to have the response type as xml.

Refer to this [Spring guide](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc) for examples and variations on this theme and on configuration settings.

Hope this helps,

Jake

Comment: thanks for your reply but its not what I expected. Content-negotiation is to check/ignore Accept header and to give response as default. My question was: How to overwrite the Accept header default/request's and based on business logic how to set response Content Type dynamically ? I tried to HTTPHeaders but no luck

Comment: @Krish I understood your question correctly. Your goal is, to ignore the Accept header and respond in a format decided on the backend without even trying to agree with the consumer about a commonly supported format. Referring to [MDN Content-Negotiation]([https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation]) , wether you implement Server or Agent driven negotiation, at the end of the day, both parties must first agree on a format before proceeding otherwise, the consumer won't be able to process the response (re: 200-OK 
 with error Unexpected '<' when expecting JSON).